# read() in linux for event file

Tags: linux, system-calls

I'm writing a program to track the mouse movements in linux. I read in another post that this can be done using read() system call to read the EventX file related to the mouse. I earlier was reading the serial port file and i used the read() to read it. But, then i sent in a character array to it and got back the serial characters. But, it doesnt seem to be in the mouse's case. The lines:

```
struct input_event ie;
read(fd, &ie, sizeof(struct input_event)
```

are used to read it. Here the ie is a struct. But i used to send in a char buffer in the serial port case. So, my question is: how do I know what struct/buffer to send. I got to know the answer for the above two code lines after googling, but if I want to read some other file,how would i know what struct/buffer to send. Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for some sort of master list of structure to device?

Comment: Generally you use some [X11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11) server....

Comment: Yeah, sort of, atleast something that defines the kind of variable it reads to. This the prototype: ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);

Answer (score 0):

The input subsystem in Linux uses a standarized format to deliver its messages. It is actually quite simple:

1. You open the relevant input file, usually `/dev/input/event<n>`, using the `open()` system call.
2. You read input events from that file, using the `read()` function, as you noted in your question.

Every event from that file has a well known structure: that is `struct input_event`. You don't need to know the exact layout of that structure, that is done by the compiler. Just include the relevant header file: `#include <linux/input.h>`.

What you do want to know are the fields of this structure that are useful, and what they mean. I recommend you to read the [official documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/event-codes.txt) as well as the [`input.h`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/input.h) source.

Comment: Got what you are saying, but are there any more types of files like event file, serial port file,and so on. Because while reading, I need to know what structure to send to read(). The prototype doesn't say this. The serila requires a char buffer while event requires struct input_event. So are there more such files and if there are, what kind of buffer has to be passed?

Comment: @jay: `read()` is a generic low-level function, it just reads bytes, hence the `void*`. When you read from a normal file, you just get what it's stored there, but when you read from a char-device, you have to check the documentation of the specific device to know what to expect. In the case of `/dev/input/event<n>` it is what I linked, but there are so many of them that it is impossible to enumerate them here.

Comment: Thank you for clearing it. Can you please give a link to find all of them? I'm feeling kinda incomplete.

Comment: All of them??? Well, you can start reading the [kernel docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/). There are more there that you ask for, but probably not every single char device is totally documented. But this is Open Source, so the source is available for almost every device driver (and not so hard to read once you get the trick) . Remember: source code is the ultimate documentation!

Comment: that was what I required. By "all of them" i imagined a small number. This is quite large. But anyway, now atleast have a bundled information that i could go through. Thank you for the help!